# Start Java Swings application on Solaris box from JSP

Tags: java, jsp

We have standalone Java Swing based application which got deployed on Solaris OS, We want to gave an option in JSP which should start Java Swings application on the server.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Sampath

Comment: Why do you want to start a Java Swing (Desktop) application on the server through JSP? You will most likely not see anything from the Swing UI ...

Comment: Java swing application is based on Desktop application , for web application you have to use any J2ee web technology.

Comment: Perhaps you should investigate java web start.

Comment: Thanks for the support, we newly introduced opengeo web client for GNIP application (JSP),  An option of opengeo web client (JSP) should start the another client which was implemented in Java Swings.